# Misaligned cells using makecell and xtabular

Tags: tables, makecell

First a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xtab}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{|p{0.65cm}||C{0.7cm}|C{0.7cm}|C{0.7cm}|C{0.7cm}|C{0.7cm}|C{0.7cm}|C{0.7cm}|}
\hline
\texttt{col}& A 
            & B
            & C 
            & D
            & E
            & F
            & G
\\\hline
\hline
\texttt{1}      &\makecell{0/5\\10/20}
                &\makecell{0/5\\---}
                &\makecell{---\\10/10}
                &\makecell{0/5\\10/20}
                &\makecell{---\\10/20}
                &\makecell{---\\10/20}
                &\makecell{0/5\\0/20}
\\\hline
\texttt{2}      &\makecell{0/10\\5/5}
                &\makecell{0/10\\---}
                &\makecell{---\\5/5}
                &\makecell{0/10\\5/5}
                &\makecell{---\\5/5}
                &\makecell{---\\5/5}
                &\makecell{0/10\\0/5}
\\\hline
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Example]

The columns already reach the maximal width.

In the example in the first row B-1 is not like the others, in the second row C-2, E-2 and F-2 are misaligned.

What I want to achieve is that in each row both lines of all cells are on the same height. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is the other way around: the other entries are misaligned, because the boxes are too small.

Comment: Good point. You’re right, all cells are "aligned" (=all misaligned) if I force an "overflow" in the other cells, too. ![Example](https://s27.postimg.org/xssp2xnsz/table_stackoverflow2.png) The first problem is "solved" causing another problem: Having such a big white space at the bottom does not look good. Can this be solved? Larger columns are not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by larger columns are not possible? What are exactly the constraints? You can reduce the inter-column space by setting `\tabcolsep` to a smaller value, so that you gain horizontal space, or you can use a smaller font such that the contents of the cells fits into a width of `0.7cm`. It is definitely no solution to cause an overflow in all cells and then to reduce the space at the bottom that results from this error.

Comment: There seems also to be extra space at the border of each cell, introduced by `\makecell`. See the docs of `makecell` on how to adjust this space. If you tell us what the hard constraints are (like total table width or whatever), we can help you in adjusting the flexible parts.

Comment: The table will later be used in a two-column page document (that’s why I use xtabular) and I will not have enough space to simply enlarge the columns (the column-sizes are already the maximum that is possible). May I should have written that in the first post.  

I will try your other suggested solutions and see if I can manage it that the content fits into the cells. Also will have a look into the makecell documentation.

Comment: Zarkos (making the left column a multirowcell and changing the other column in the suggested way) solution will work for me; thanks for your help, too! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As supplement to *gernot* nice answer, but with preserved vertical lines and simplified writing of cells contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,makecell,multirow}
\usepackage{xtab}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
{\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells 
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{xtabular}{|>{\ttfamily}l||*{7}{C{0.9cm}|}}
    \hline
col & A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
    \hline
    \hline
\multirowcell{2}{1}      
    &   0/5    10/20
    &   0/5    ---
    &   ---    10/10
    &   0/5    10/20
    &   ---    10/20
    &   ---    10/20
    &   0/5    0/20             \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{2}{2}
    &   0/10   5/5
    &   0/10   ---
    &   ---    5/5
    &   0/10   5/5
    &   ---    5/5
    &   ---    5/5
    &   0/10   0/5              \\
    \hline
\end{xtabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

For a better alignment and spacing:

- Enlarge the width of the columns to `0.9cm`. The misalignment is caused by columns that are too narrow, so most entries (except those that you thought are misaligned) are misaligned.
- Save horizontal space by removing the vertical lines
- Make the table better readable by removing the vertical lines
- Improve the spacing and the horizontal lines by using the package `booktabs` and its horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xtab}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{p{0.7cm}C{0.9cm}C{0.9cm}C{0.9cm}C{0.9cm}C{0.9cm}C{0.9cm}C{0.9cm}}
\toprule
\texttt{col}& A 
            & B
            & C 
            & D
            & E
            & F
            & G
\\\midrule
\texttt{1}      &\makecell{0/5\\10/20}
                &\makecell{0/5\\---}
                &\makecell{---\\10/10}
                &\makecell{0/5\\10/20}
                &\makecell{---\\10/20}
                &\makecell{---\\10/20}
                &\makecell{0/5\\0/20}
\\\midrule
\texttt{2}      &\makecell{0/10\\5/5}
                &\makecell{0/10\\---}
                &\makecell{---\\5/5}
                &\makecell{0/10\\5/5}
                &\makecell{---\\5/5}
                &\makecell{---\\5/5}
                &\makecell{0/10\\0/5}
\\\bottomrule
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```